# error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later

Tags: angular

Fast answers could be appreciated.
here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's too late to answer this; but even i faced this and it was resolved by giving the lib file directly as an argument while compiling the TS file.
tsc   --lib

Answer (score 1):

If using Visual Studio add the Nuget package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: In my vs2022 website solution, there is an issue same too when I build. after I install the package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild, then reopen the solution, and build the whole project, there is no any errors appear again. Thanks